# Does CartoDB automatically fill in Polygon data for city/state?

Tags: carto, polygonize

I'd like to upload a spreadsheet that has custom city/state information and have CartoDB automatically fill in the polygon data.

If this is possible, then how?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, CartoDB just recognizes columns for latitude and longitude (called 'lat¡, 'long', 'latitude', or 'longitude').

We are working to make also available the recognition of further columns, as 'country'. So what you mention is not still available, but we're on it! :-)